# MomentJS: Compare time in different timezones

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I have array of timezones and I want to know which one is the 'earliest one' where earliest is the one in the earliest time zone.

For example:

- Timezone X is Thursday 5pm
- Timezone Y is Thursday 7pm

Than X is the earliest among them.

I'm using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) and [momentjs-timzone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) in NodeJS (not the browser package)

I'm trying to compare the millisecond timestamp but this give me the same value for both:

```
if (momenttz().tz(timezoneX).format('x') > momenttz().tz(timezoneY).format('x'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NodeJS syntax it can accomplished by formatting timezones to offset values, finding the minimum component and returning its Timezone value:

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');

var inputTzArray = ['Pacific/Chatham', 'America/St_Johns', 'Asia/Jerusalem', 'America/New_York', 'America/Los_Angeles'];
var tzOffsets = []
for (var i in inputTzArray) {
   var s = moment.tz(inputTzArray[i]).format('Z'); //format to offset
   tzOffsets[i] = parseFloat(s.replace(':','.')); //parse int offset
}
console.log(tzOffsets);
var minIndex = tzOffsets.indexOf(Math.min.apply(Math, tzOffsets)); //find minimum's index

console.log(inputTzArray[minIndex]); //Output earliest timezone
```

A live demo by running "node server.js" in the interactive console in the link: http://runnable.com/VJ3M3XdZAVg-EVOP